# Horizontal scrollbar appears even though no element is wider than container?

Tags: css, scrollbar

Here is my CSS. I've calculated width for all elements, but I just can't seem to find the culprit.
I did mess around with the code, and when header-nav is set to 850px or less, the scrollbar disappears. Please help?

```
html, body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
        font-size: 10pt;
        color: #222222;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1200px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(images/container-bg.png) repeat-y;
}

#header-nav {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(images/header-bg.png) no-repeat;
}

#menu{
    position: relative;
    top: 95px;
    left: 390px;
    list-style:none;
    z-index:5;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 101px;
    width: 230px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#main {
    position: relative;
    left: 351px;
    width: 720px;
    min-height: 600px;
    padding: 15px;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    left: 101px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 980px;
    height: 99px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: url(images/footer-border.png) no-repeat;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle so that we can help?

Comment: Just added a fiddle.

Comment: there isn't a scrollbar in the fiddle when the browser is greater than 1200 px. please have a look. if its still there, can you explain the question?
edit:- ctrl+shift+top-arrow to toggle the sidebar.

Comment: It's strange. I don't see a scrollbar in the fiddle, either. However, as you can see if you follow the second link, there is a scrollbar. The CSS for the website and the fiddle is exactly the same, and even when I remove all content, the scrollbar stays.

Comment: Oh, I just figured it out. It was the navigation bar that was messing up things. The fiddle did help. Thanks to you, too!

Comment: you worked it out yourself. great. happy to help.